# How did heap come up?

Tags: data-structures, heap

I know heap data structure very well and used it to various applications before. But just wonder how the basic idea comes from? How a person would figure out a non-trivial structure with some specific properties? Can we invent some new structures through the similar ideas in our own cases?

Comment: How does a human being figure out an idea which hasn't been thought of before... good question in general... If you can answer that, then you can probably figure out all remaining ideas which haven't been thought of as of yet...

Comment: I didn't want to figure out ALL new ideas. :-) Just want to know if there is any method to invent non-trivial structures on our own. If it exists, what would it be?

Comment: All known methods have already been used for inventing all known structures. There are definitely methods for inventing new structures, but they are all unknown (if they were known, then someone would have used them by now).

Comment: "How did somebody invent something?" is not a constructive or **answerable** question. Likewise "Can we invent new data structures?" does not make any sense. Who would stop you? You can do anything you want.

Comment: Not really. Knowing the ideas behind would help us do better. It is different from "Can we invent something?". It is about "How we invent something useful?"

Answer (score 1):

The first published use of the heap structure appears to be by Robert J. Floyd in his Algorithm 113, Treesort, in 1962: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=368637.368654. His heap was a traditional tree, implemented with node pointers.

J.W.J. Williams published an algorithm, Heapsort (Algorithm 232), in 1964. It converted Floyd's node-based heap into the array-based binary heap that we all know and love. That was in the June 1964 issue of Communications of the ACM. I wasn't able to find a link to the reference on the ACM site.

Neither really says how he came to discover the structure.